# using inorm in R - normalisation of large data frame

Tags: r

I have a data frame containing 280 observations and 497 variables. The variables are both imaging variables acquired using MRI and cognitive/behavioural variables. I would like to normalise my data frame before I run PCA.

I have tried to use:

`inorm <- function(x) scale(qnorm((rank(x,ties='average')-1/2)/(length(x))`

As I need to apply it to my entire data frame I believe I should also be using `apply` or `lapply`?

However, I am unsure where exactly I should include apply/lapply and if the above is even correct...

Please help!

Many Thanks!

Comment: Thank you! Is there any good examples of doing this that you can recommend?

Comment: Hey again. Thank you for writing back. Unfortunately, that link really was not helpful. It would be great to get a step by step example of how to run PCA. Also, I will need to normalise the entire data set...

Comment: That doesn't work for my data set either :(. I am not sure how else to go about it... I have found some links online that run through how to do PCA on your dataset, but they are so different... Very confused!!